# Angular.js googlemap info window button click is not passing the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here i am showing some cities with infowindow everything is working but in that info window i have one button.if i click that button(get) it should pass the value to function .any one help me out

now when i click that button nothing is showing in console my demo 
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5z86v5ay/13/)

```js
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
        .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $compile) {
            var cities = [{
                id: '02jdjd',
                city: 'Toronto',
                desc: 'World Largest city,This city is live,This is the second best city in the world',
    lat: 43.7000,
                long: -79.4000,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsss',
                city: 'New York',
    desc: 'coastal area,This city is aiiiiite, ',
                lat: 40.6700,
                long: -73.9400,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssws',
                city: 'Chicago',
    desc: 'This is the second best city in the world',
                lat: 41.8819,
                long: -87.6278,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdsssz',
                city: 'Los Angeles',
    desc: 'This city is live,coastal area,incredible city',
                lat: 34.0500,
                long: -118.2500,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
            }, {
                id: '02jdjdssq',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
    desc: 'the most populous city,This city is live,This city is aiiiiite',
                lat: 36.0800,
                long: -115.1522,
    icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'
            }];

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            $scope.markers = [];

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var createMarker = function(info) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                    title: info.city,
     icon: info.icon
                });
                marker.content = '<div><h2>'+marker.title+'</h2><input type="button" value="get" ng-click="get(\'' + info.id + '\')"/>' + '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div></div>';
                // marker.content = "<div><h2>" + marker.title + "</h2><input type='button' value='get' ng-click='get(" + info.id + ")'/>" + "<div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.desc + "</div><div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.city + "</div></div>";
                google.maps.event.addListener(
                    marker,
                    'click', (function(marker, $scope) {
                        return function() {
                            var compiled = $compile(marker.content)($scope);
                            $scope.$apply();
                            infoWindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
                            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        };
                    })(marker, $scope)
                );

                $scope.markers.push(marker);
            }
            $scope.get = function(city) {
                console.log(city);
                //alert("from $scope.get id : "+id); 
            }
            for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                createMarker(cities[i]);
            }

            $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
            }




            $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
                    $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                $scope.markers.length = 0;
            }



            $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
                //1.select filtered cities
                var filteredCities;
                var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
                if (cityDesc == '0') {
                    filteredCities = cities;
                } else {
                    filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
                        if (c.desc == cityDesc)
                            return c;
                    });
                }
                //2.update markers on map
                $scope.clearMarkers();
                for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(filteredCities[i]);
                }
            }

        }]);
    //]]>
```

```css
#map {
        height: 420px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    
    .infoWindowContent {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Filter Marker </label>
        <br>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
            <option value="0">all</option>
            <option value="This is the best city in the world">This is the best city in the world</option>
            <option value="This city is aiiiiite">This city is aiiiiite</option>
            <option value="the most populous city">the most populous city</option>
            <option value="This city is live">This city is live</option>
   <option value="coastal area">coastal area</option>
   <option value="World Largest city">World Largest city</option>
   <option value="incredible city">incredible city</option>
   
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this approach re-uses same infoWindow for every marker, this means that multiple markers cannot be open at the same time. Apart from that, try to set initial content in infoWindow `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:''});`

Comment: same time i don't want to open multiple info window.pls can you help me out for passing id

Comment: add the id as a `data-attribute` and get it off from the element using `get`, e.g `<input type="button" value="get" data-marker-id="'+info.id+'" ng-click="get(this)" />` function `get` could be like `function get(el){ var id = el.getAttribute('data-marker-id'); /*..*/}`

Comment: no it's not working.if i click it's not passing the value

Comment: then use `$scope` instead of `this` i dont use angular but i think this is what it needs. It manages scope through the `$scope` object so use that to pass the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this should do i guess

*little explanation: The issue is, you are trying to call angular function from custom html, which was never linked to angular , so you have to compile it first.*

Basically **$compile(marker.content)($scope);**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    #map {
        height: 420px;
        width: 600px;
    }
    
    .infoWindowContent {
        font-size: 14px !important;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    //Angular App Module and Controller
    angular.module('mapsApp', [])
        .controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $compile) {
            var cities = [{
                id: '1',
                city: 'Toronto',
                desc: 'This is the best city in the world!',
                lat: 43.7000,
                long: -79.4000
            }, {
                id: '2',
                city: 'New York',
                desc: 'This city is aiiiiite!',
                lat: 40.6700,
                long: -73.9400
            }, {
                id: '3',
                city: 'Chicago',
                desc: 'This is the second best city in the world!',
                lat: 41.8819,
                long: -87.6278
            }, {
                id: '4',
                city: 'Los Angeles',
                desc: 'This city is live!',
                lat: 34.0500,
                long: -118.2500
            }, {
                id: '5',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
                desc: 'This city is live!',
                lat: 36.0800,
                long: -115.1522
            }];

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }

            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            $scope.markers = [];

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var createMarker = function(info) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: $scope.map,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                    title: info.city
                });
                marker.content = '<div><h2>'+marker.title+'</h2><input type="button" value="get" ng-click="get(' + info.id + ')"/>' + '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div><div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.city + '</div></div>';

                google.maps.event.addListener(
                    marker,
                    'click', (function(marker, $scope) {
                        return function() {
                            var compiled = $compile(marker.content)($scope);
                            $scope.$apply();
                            infoWindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
                            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                        };
                    })(marker, $scope)
                );

                $scope.markers.push(marker);
            }
            $scope.get = function(id) {
                console.log(id);
                //alert("from $scope.get id : "+id); 
            }
            for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                createMarker(cities[i]);
            }

            $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
                e.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
            }




            $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
                    $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                $scope.markers.length = 0;
            }



            $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
                //1.select filtered cities
                var filteredCities;
                var cityDesc = $scope.data.singleSelect;
                if (cityDesc == '0') {
                    filteredCities = cities;
                } else {
                    filteredCities = cities.filter(function(c) {
                        if (c.desc == cityDesc)
                            return c;
                    });
                }
                //2.update markers on map
                $scope.clearMarkers();
                for (i = 0; i < filteredCities.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(filteredCities[i]);
                }
            }

        }]);
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Filter Marker </label>
        <br>
        <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()">
            <option value="0">all</option>
            <option value="This is the best city in the world!">This is the best city in the world!</option>
            <option value="This city is aiiiiite">This city is aiiiiite</option>
            <option value="This is the second best city in the world!">This is the second best city in the world!</option>
            <option value="This city is live!">This city is live!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
            <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how can i add more details in info window?

Comment: plz refer updated answer, actually u must be creating custom directives for it, this is not the best approach

Comment: i want to know one thing is it possible to design popup window ?for me if i click marker instead of info window onw div should come with left arrow and right arrow like slider is it possible to design?

Comment: instead of that id i am passing desc <input type="button" value="get" ng-click="get('+info.desc+')"/>.i am getting error like this Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/syntax?p0=%3A&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=9&p3=get(http%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fridefinder%2Fimages%2Fmm_20_green.png)&p4=%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fridefinder%2Fimages%2Fmm_20_green.png)
    at Error (native)
    at

Comment: first thing u r using wrong " and ' 
and it did work `marker.content = "<div><h2>" + marker.title + "</h2><input type='button' value='get' ng-click='get(" + info.id + ")'/>" + "<div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.desc + "</div><div class='infoWindowContent'>" + info.city + "</div></div>";`

Comment: no instead of id u try desc it's not working .it's passing undefined

Comment: if i pass id it's working.if i pass some city or desc it's not working getting error and it's showing undefined

Comment: did u check?if i put id 0303dad30 some thing like this its not passing

Comment: c'mon dude put this `ng-click="get(\'' + info.desc + '\')"/>'` this is pretty basic and for this u unaccepted my answer. u have to pass parameter as string which is done by escape character `\\`

Comment: i am new to this technology sorry dont mistake me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95836/discussion-between-aishwat-singh-and-martin).

Comment: pls check i have updated my demo and code .my filter is not working pls can u help me out